# 0X1C error on APRS.FI

Tags: aprs

I get a 0X1C error in APRS.FI and my beacon does not show on ui-view32. I am totally lost. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
2020-04-13 19:19:38 CDT: W5CCL-10>TVRX0X,WIDE*,WIDE2-1,qAR,W0RC:'yVel <0x1c>Y\]=
2020-04-13 19:29:54 CDT: W5CCL-10>TVRX0X,WIDE1-1,WIDE2-1,qAR,W0KGW-10:'yVel <0x1c>Y\]=
```

Comment: Is your station W5CCL-10 or TVRX0X?  What software/device is generating the beacon?  IIRC, if your beacon doesn't include position information (Lat/Long for example) it won't show on APRS-FI either.  And for more info about the INFO field, there's this question: https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/10336/help-understanding-the-information-field-in-an-aprs-is-message

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: @Duston W5CCL-10 is the sender, TVRX0X is the TOCALL, and that's a Mic-E format packet. It does contain a location.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your packet and `<0x1c>` is not an error. Your packet is a neatly formed Mic-E packet with a position of 46°28'08" N, 93°58'73" W, a speed/course of 0 (not moving), a status message of "Off Duty", a symbol of "radio or APRS device", and a type/version code of Kenwood D710. The `<0x1c>` character is part of the encoding of the zero speed.

I don't think there's adequate information in your post to guess why your position doesn't display in UI-View32; aprs.fi and APRS Direct were perfectly happy with it. It's worth noting that the author of UI-View32 passed away more than 15 years ago, so any bugs it may have are pretty well "frozen in" at this point. You may want to investigate other options.